# Java EE perspective in STS(Spring Tool Suite)

Tags: spring-tool-suite, perspective

I'm using Spring Tool Suite(STS) and to run Java Servlets on Tomcat Server through STS I need **Java EE** perspective. But for me in list of perspectives in STS there is no **Java EE** perspective.

How do I get **Java EE** perspective in STS??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get **Java EE** perspective in Spring Tool Suite(STS),

1. Go to `Help` > `Eclipse Marketplace...`
   and search for **Java EE**

[image]

2. Search for the **Eclipse Enterprise Java and Web Developers Tools**

[image]

Now just install the **Eclipse Enterprise Java and Web Developers Tools** plugin and then your
list of perspective will look like this now

[image]